# how to set IP Address manual with command line(not GUI) but the network connection through WLAN (WiFi)

Tags: networking

I have configured the **interfaces** file in the directory **/etc/network**

```
 # DHCP not needed
 # iface wlan2 inet dhcp
      auto wlan2
      iface wlan2 inet static
      address 192.168.23.11
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.23.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

the **resolv.conf** file in the directory **/etc/** i add its **dns-server**

```
   # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
   # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
     nameserver 8.8.8.8
     search mynetwork.local
```

the **hosts** file in the directory **/etc/** i add ip manuals

```
   192.168.23.11     Yudi
```

after I configure it all, I tried to restart the IP configuration with the command

```
$ sudo ifdown lo && sudo ifup lo
```

but the configuration is not successful, I also have to restart the laptop but also to no avail..
what's the solution?

Comment: `lo` isn't `eth0`. Try `sudo service networking restart` or even `eth0` instead of `lo`

Comment: `eth0` won't work for wifi.

Comment: Also, `service networking restart` is actually deprecated.

Comment: Oh, I see, wlan2, not eth0

Comment: IMHO if you want to configure your wireless connection, it's much easier to do it from NetworkManager or wicd. Going the /etc/network/interfaces way is more suited for servers that don't have GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

With your command you did only restart the loopback interface, not the interface you edited.

Usually you stop the network interface you want to edit (`wlan2` in your case) with `ifdown`, before you edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and bring it up with `ifup` afterwards.

Try executing `ifup wlan2`. Make sure there is no network manager installed trying to configure the wifi itself and make sure `wlan2` is the correct interface.

Comment: I have tried to run the command
$ Sudo ifup wlan2

Comment: remain misconfigured, 
I try to add syntax on file interfaces /etc/network
:

wpa-ssid <SSID>
WPA-PSK <password_SSID>

but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Setting up static IP address can be done through `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file by adding this at the end of the file:

```
interface "wlan2" {
    send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.23.11;
}
```

This is a compromise between using a static IP yet using DHCP.  Your dhcp client will send request to the dhcp server for that specific address whenever you connect to a router. The other parts, such as `dns-nameserver` can be configured in the middle of the file, by adding line `supersede domain-name-serves xxx.xxx.xxx.xx`. For example, here is part of my file:

```
#send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
send host-name = gethostname();
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220; # THIS LINE HERE
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

The netmask and gateway can be left to be configured automatically. All editing can be done with command line text editors such as `nano` and `vi` or even batch editors like `sed` or `awk`